# Gradle issues with Auto-generated code like Dagger2 in Continuous Integration

Tags: android, gradle, travis-ci, circleci, dagger-2

I am using `AutoParcel` and `Dagger2` for autogenerated code, which requires use of the gradle `android-apt` plugin. Which means that the first compile fails, but when you run the task for a second time, it succeeds. Normally this is only a slight annoyance, but this becomes a big issue with continuous integration tools like CircleCI or TravisCI, which always run clean builds.

```
./gradlew :app:clean
./gradlew :app:compileDebugJava   //fails
./gradlew :app:compileDebugJava   //succeeds
```

How can an Android dev get around this? Obviously, I do not want every CI build to report a failure.

**circle.yml**

```
test:
  pre:
     - ./gradlew :android:compileDebugJava -PdisablePreDex
  override:
     - ./gradlew :android:compileDebugJava -PdisablePreDex
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `|| true` will report a failing task as successful with CircleCI.

```
test:
  pre:
     - ./gradlew :android:compileDebugJava -PdisablePreDex || true
  override:
     - ./gradlew :android:compileDebugJava -PdisablePreDex
```